# Datepicker onselect redirect with variable

Tags: php, jquery

When choosing the date, I want that date to be inserting in link and loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(date) {
                window.location.replace("http://localhost/news-archive/$date/-/");
            }
    });
  })
```

Function works, only problem is how to insert date value in link? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `window.location.replace("http://localhost/news-archive/"+date+"/-/");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

window.location.replace("http://localhost/news-archive/"+date.concat("/-/"));

Comment: my fault, missed a ")" in the end